# Not getting anything return from query written in php file

Tags: android, mysql

**PHP file**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql3.000webhost.com","a9225790_studio","pwd","a9225790_studio");

$sub=$_REQUEST['$subject'];

$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from Questions where Subject='$sub'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($data)>0)
{
  $resp['question-status']="SUCCESS";

  while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
  {
         $resp['Questions'].=$r['Question'].",".$r['Option1'].",".$r['Option2'].",".$r['Option3'].",".$r['Option4'].",".$r['Answer'].";";
}
echo json_encode($resp);
}
else
{
$resp['question-status']="ERROR";
echo json_encode($resp);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Select query not returning anything for the $sub Subject. However Question,options and answer for the corresponding $sub Subject is there in the table.
It always going in else loop

$resp['question-status']="ERROR";

**Android Code**

```
public class Exam extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView no,ques;
RadioGroup op;
RadioButton op1,op2,op3,op4;
Button ne,pass,submit;
String correctAnswer,userAnswer,n,subject;
int totalQuestion,currentQuestion;

ArrayList<String> allQuestion=new ArrayList<String>();
int score=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam);

    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    n=b.getString("UN");
    subject=b.getString("SUB");


    userAnswer="";

   // time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    //totq=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.totq);
    no=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.no);
    ques=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ques);
    op=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.op);
    op1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1);
    op2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2);
    op3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3);
    op4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4);
    ne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ne);
    pass=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    ne.setOnClickListener(this);
    pass.setOnClickListener(this);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    op1.setOnClickListener(new MyAnswerListener());
    op2.setOnClickListener(new MyAnswerListener());
    op3.setOnClickListener(new MyAnswerListener());
    op4.setOnClickListener(new MyAnswerListener());

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> list=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject",subject));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),subject,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String res=MyJsonToStringConverter.convert(list,"http://rgworks.site90.net/android_studio/e_exam/FetchQuestions.php");
    try
    {

        JSONObject j=new JSONObject(res);
        if(j.getString("question-status").equals("SUCCESS"))
        {
            String [] data=j.getString("Questions").split(";");
            for (String s1 : data)
            {
                allQuestion.add(s1);
            }
        }
        else if(j.getString("question-status").equals("ERROR"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No questions available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_e", e.toString());
    }

    totalQuestion=allQuestion.size();

    if (totalQuestion == 0)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Question",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        nextQuestion();
    }

}

    public void nextQuestion()
    {
        String [] q1=allQuestion.get(currentQuestion).split(",");
        no.setText(String.valueOf(currentQuestion+1 +"."+" "));
        ques.setText(q1[0]);
        op1.setText(q1[1]);
        op2.setText(q1[2]);
        op3.setText(q1[3]);
        op4.setText(q1[4]);
        correctAnswer=q1[5];
        op.clearCheck();
    }
```

And in the android code i have checked for the value of 'subject' by printing it in Toast. Before sending this value to Php file it is Successfully printed. But in the php code it is unable to get anything from the table for the Subject '$sub'.

Answer (score 0):

First i would suggest that you use PDO instead of mysqli in your php.
The php code seems ok but PDO is better agents sql injection.
And in your Android code use Volley i can give you good tutorials so you can learn ti, it is easy, if you want